# Composer and ext-xdebug? Can't install anything

Tags: composer-php, xdebug

Whatever I do in composer, I get this message

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                    
Package is not installed: ext-xdebug-2.4.1.0
```

I have tried actually installing that package and get the same error.
Any suggestions?

Running Arch Linux with composer as global.

EDIT: as you can see, I have xdebug installed and enabled.

```
╭[andrew@TheSandbox] : [~]
╰>php -v
PHP 7.0.14 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2016 17:11:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

╭[andrew@TheSandbox] : [~]
╰>php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
xdebug
...

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

Comment: Can you please add the output of `php -v` and `php -m`? Maybe the extension is installed, but **not enabled**?

Comment: Edited to show requested info

Comment: please provide your composer.json require and require-dev sections. Typically this can be resolved by using a specific version of php and then no version constraint on the extensions e.g. `"ext-xdebug": "*"` If this is an issue with a vendor package you can use: `php composer.phar require <package> --ignore-platform-reqs` to by-pass the platform requirements of php and the extensions.